# Why is pthread not using the given stack space?

Tags: c, memory, pthreads, stack

When creating a new `pthread` and passing it an argument modified with `pthread_attr_getstack` it seems to not using the defined stack space.

```
void* thread_function(void * ptr)
{
  int a;
  printf("stack var in thread %p\n",&a);
}


int main( int argc , char **argv )
{
  pthread_t thread;
  void * ptr = NULL;
  const int stack_size = 10*1024;

  void * stack = malloc(stack_size);
  printf("alloc=%p\n",&stack);

  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setstack( &attr , stack , stack_size );

  if (pthread_create(&thread, &attr, &thread_function , ptr ) ) {
    printf("failed to create thread\n");
    return 1;
  }

  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
  pthread_exit( 0 );
  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the output is:

```
alloc=0x7fff48989bc8
stack var in thread 0x7f6e6f0d2ebc
```

Even if stack grows backward (which i am not sure) the pointer values differ so much, that only hope that the created thread uses a different virtual memory address space. But i think this is not the case.

Comment: Why don't you print the address of the allocated memory instead of the address of the local variable 'stack'? I mean: printf("alloc=%p\n",stack);

Comment: @Adriano He does that too. That's how we can see that the local variable is NOT within the allocated area.

Comment: @nos I missed something! :O malloc will allocate on the heap (say address 100). 'stack' is allocated on the stack of main (say address 10). If everything works the variable "a" should be (more or less) at address 100. But if you print the address of &stack you'll see 10, not 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing the wrong thing,

```
printf("alloc=%p\n",&stack);
```

Prints the address of a local stack variable, not the allocated memory. You have to do

```
printf("alloc=%p\n",stack);
```

Also, you need to check for errors:

> ERRORS
>
> ```
>    pthread_attr_setstack() can fail with the following error:
>
>    EINVAL stacksize is less than PTHREAD_STACK_MIN (16384) bytes.  On some
>           systems, this error may also occur if stackaddr or
>           stackaddr + stacksize is not suitably aligned.
> ```

You've only set a stack of 10kB, so try again with a bigger stack, and check the return value of pthread_attr_setstack.

I'd probably try to make the stack page aligned as well.

Comment: You probably want to use something like `posix_memalign` to be safe too.